# Syntax error in R script with for loop

Tags: r

I am writing a simple R script (script.r).

I want R to read in 13 serially numbered tables ("table1.txt", "table2.txt", etc.), then select a particular column ("dosage"), and multiply each of the 13 outputs by a different factor, and then sum them all at the end.

```
for (i in 1:13) {
    loci[i]<-read.table("table[i].txt, header=T)
    dloc[i]<-(loc[i]$dosage)
    logdloc1<-(dloc1*0.077)
    logdloc2<-(dloc2*-0.105)
    logdloc3<-(dloc3*0.104)
    logdloc4<-(dloc4*0.113)
    logdloc5<-(dloc5*-0.105)
    logdloc6<-(dloc6*0.131)
    logdloc7<-(dloc7*-0.117)
    logdloc8<-(dloc8*-0.083)
    logdloc9<-(dloc9*-0.083)
    logdloc10<-(dloc10*0.182)
    logdloc11<-(dloc11*0.157)
    logdloc12<-(dloc12*0.086)
    logdloc13<-(dloc13*0.27)
    output<-(logdloc1 + logdloc2 + logdloc3 + logdloc4 + logdloc5 + logdloc6 + logdloc7 + logdloc8 + logdloc9 + logdloc10 + logdloc11 + logdloc12 + logdloc13)}
```

I know there's a syntax error, because I get an error message when I try to execute it in command line:

```
Rscript script.r
Error: unexpected end of input
```

Can somebody very kindly spot the obvious?

Very grateful for your help.

AB

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing "

```
for (i in 1:13) {
    loci[i]<-read.table("table[i].txt", header=T)
    dloc[i]<-(loc[i]$dosage)
    logdloc1<-(dloc1*0.077)
    logdloc2<-(dloc2*-0.105)
    logdloc3<-(dloc3*0.104)
    logdloc4<-(dloc4*0.113)
    logdloc5<-(dloc5*-0.105)
    logdloc6<-(dloc6*0.131)
    logdloc7<-(dloc7*-0.117)
    logdloc8<-(dloc8*-0.083)
    logdloc9<-(dloc9*-0.083)
    logdloc10<-(dloc10*0.182)
    logdloc11<-(dloc11*0.157)
    logdloc12<-(dloc12*0.086)
    logdloc13<-(dloc13*0.27)
    output<-(logdloc1 + logdloc2 + logdloc3 + logdloc4 + logdloc5 + logdloc6 + logdloc7 + logdloc8 + logdloc9 + logdloc10 + logdloc11 + logdloc12 + logdloc13)}
```

## Edit

Based on coment, i guess that `table` is an r object so you should replace this line by:

```
loci[i]<-read.table(paste0(table[i], ".txt"), header=T)
```

which will paste the ith element to ".txt".

For a more complete answer, please precise what is in `table`

Comment: Thank you - that was very sloppy of me. Have now executed with the " in place. 
But I am now encountering another error message:
  "cannot open file 'table[i].txt': No such file or directory".
Even though I have table1.txt to table13.txt within that directory. Why could this be?
Thank you.

Comment: I eddited answer please check it and complete your question